# Django Many-to-Many data model

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm trying to create a data structure that involves Products, Customers and Orders. Customers and Products are independent tables, while the Orders references Products and Customers.

Orders table fields:

1. Time stamp
2. Customer
3. Product along with Quantity

Here is my attempt at creating a django model to achieve this:

```
from django.db import models

class Customer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    latitude = models.FloatField(default=0)
    longitude = models.FloatField(default=0)

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    weight = models.FloatField(default=0)

class Order(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    products = models.ManyToManyField(Product)
    quantity = ?
```

How do I create a quantity field that maps to a particular product? Alternate models to achieve the same results are also welcome.

Comment: For those looking for how to use this model in django admin, this should help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6034047/one-to-many-inline-select-with-django-admin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [through](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships) in your ManyToManyField.

```
from django.db import models

class Customer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    latitude = models.FloatField(default=0)
    longitude = models.FloatField(default=0)

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    weight = models.FloatField(default=0)

class Order(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    line_items = models.ManyToManyField(Product, through='OrderItem')

class OrderItem(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order)
    quantity, price, discount, ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a model which contain a product and its quantity in an order. Something like below.

```
class ProductOrder(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
```

Then in order:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    products = models.ManyToManyField(ProductOrder)
```

Comment: Thank you, this was in the correct direction. What worked for me is the "through ="