# Using multiselect widget for a ForeignKey field Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-1.8

Good day i seem to be lost in how i want to implement something. so here is how it goes

ive got a carowner model

```
 class carowner(models.Model):
     .....
     carowner = models.CharField(primary_key=True)
```

and a cars model

```
class car(models.Model):
    ....
    carowner_id = models.ForeignKey(carowner)
```

it has a foreignkey cause each car can only have one carowner
but a carowner can have many cars but i run into a situation where

ive got a modelform

```
class assigncarownertocar(forms.ModelForm):
    car= forms.ModelChoiceField(widget=MultipleSelect())
    class Meta:
        model=carowner
        fields = [# all fields that are needed ]
```

what i want to happen is when im creating a new carowner asigns him multiple cars  in the same form from a  queryset i provided when the modelform is initialized. 
so everything loads fine in the form. i see the list of cars but once i select one or more i get this

> 'Select a valid choice. 539421 is not one of the available choices.

what i am asking is should i add the modelmultiplechoicefield to the model that holds the foreign key?
cause right now i have it attached to the carowner model. i dont see documentation stating that this is wrong

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6034047/one-to-many-inline-select-with-django-admin