# Django: How to add button to the object creation page?

Tags: django, django-admin

I have the following models:

```
from django.db import models

class Teacher(models.Model):
    name = models.fields.CharField(max_length=255)
    favorite_student = models.ForeignKey("Student", blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.RESTRICT, related_name="+")

class Student(models.Model):
    name = models.fields.CharField(max_length=255)
    teacher = models.ForeignKey(Teacher, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


    def set_as_favorite_student(self):
        self.teacher.favorite_student = self
```

I've also registered both `Teacher` and `Student` in the admin page:

```
from .models import Teacher, Student

class TeacherAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = (
        "id",
        "name",
        "favorite_student",
    )


class StudentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = (
        "id",
        "name",
        "teacher",
    )
```

Each `teacher` must have a favorite `student`. So when there is a new `teacher`, I do the following steps:

1. Go to django admin page
2. Create a teacher
3. Create a student
4. Go back to the teacher, and set `favorite_student` to the created student

Question: For step #3, how do I create a button next to existing buttons that is `Save and set as favorite` so that I can avoid step #4?

Comment: I think this has been answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6034047/one-to-many-inline-select-with-django-admin Check the second answer